# Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'GroupBy' is not supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to do a query with Group By clause. But I'm always getting that error. The Linq expression is:

```
IEnumerable<DataType> xr_cliente = context.DataType.Where(c => c.COD_UTILIZADOR == user.IdUser)
                    .GroupBy(c => new DataType{ COD_CLIENTE = c.COD_CLIENTE, DES_CLIENTE = c.DES_CLIENTE, COD_GRUPO = c.COD_GRUPO })
                    .Select(c => new DataType{ COD_CLIENTE = c.Key.COD_CLIENTE, COD_GRUPO = c.Key.COD_GRUPO, DES_CLIENTE = c.Key.DES_CLIENTE })
                    .AsEnumerable<DataType>();
```

Is there an alternative?